# Which prepositions should I use in "Leonardo va a lavorare a Treviso___giugno ___settembre"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which prepositions should I use in this phrase?

> Leonardo va a lavorare a Treviso___giugno ___settembre.

in giugno a settembre?

nel giugno al settembre?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Are you trying to say "from July to September"?

Comment: How come you have a whole sentence with just two prepositions missing? Is that homework, by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

Month names want the *preposizione articolata* only if qualified: *nel prossimo giugno* or *nel giugno del 1985*.

Otherwise the preposition has to be simple: *andrò a Parigi in settembre*. Here *settembre* means the next September; it could mean *every September* with the present tense: *vado a Parigi in settembre*, depending on the context, can mean that I'll go to Paris the next September or that I usually go to Paris every September.

In order to speak about a time interval, we use *da… a…*. Again, the present tense can mean either that Leonardo usually works at Treviso from June to September or that he'll go there the next June till September.